# Python Openssl generate rsa key pair and write to a file

Tags: python, file, openssl, rsa, public-key

I want to generate a private , public key pair and put them into **private.key** and **public.key** files respectively.
I have the following code.

```
from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL

def gen_rsa_key_pair():
    k = crypto.PKey()
    k.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 1024)
    open("Priv.key", "wt").write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, k))
```

`crypto.dump_publickey()` is not available.

How do I dump public key to a file?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSSL functions to print the public RSA key do not seem to be exported by the Python OpenSSL wrapper. By accessing the internals of the `crypto` module, you could still do it yourself (assuming that you have this package installed locally), as this code snippet shows:

```
>>> bio = crypto._new_mem_buf()
>>> rsa = crypto._lib.EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(k._pkey)
>>> crypto._lib.PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(bio, rsa)
1
>>> s = crypto._bio_to_string(bio)
>>> print(s)
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBANF1gYh10F8HTQdM6+bkwAwJ0Md6bMciKbP3qS6KTki3v3m+cM17Szqq
Mp4xxWbvnS2oeotYfn8eaZg0QUTOVDd1F7tuOxVEdvQ9ZEp1aeOCRU3b9QZSmVfg
wJrqDG3f149mNdexI12plwaxyt6odonv6+fEQJrbhrV/nIA8N/EFAgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

This is just for illustration purposes. A proper solution should be added to the `crypto` module itself, via a new method `dump_publickey()` or the like.